# How to test Messages arriving in Azure IoTHub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have an event generator connected and publishing messages into an IoT hub. How do I check what message have arrived? I'd be interested in different ways to determine (programmatically, dashboard, etc)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a cross-platform [Azure IoT Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-toolkit) extension for Visual Studio Code to make you able to monitor the messages sent to Azure IoT Hub.

[image: device-explorer]

You could check out the [Wiki Page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-iot-toolkit/wiki) to see the full features and tutorials.

[image: Monitor-IoT-Hub-D2C-Message]

Answer (score 12):

If you want to simply test the messages, you can download the Device Explorer sample app ([open source on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer)), configure it with your connection string and monitor the messages.

[image]

Comment: Does this evict the message from IoT Hub?

Comment: Messages are deleted after the defined retention period

Comment: Device Explorer has been discontinued, source code is removed from the repo.  It has been replaced by the Azure IoT Explorer, repo is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-explorer

Answer (score 11):

Just adding two more options for future reference:

#### Azure CLI

- Follow the installation instruction to setup [Azure CLI in your environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)
- Install IoT Extension

The [IoT extension readme](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension) describes several ways to install the extension. The simplest way is to run `az extension add --name azure-iot`

At a PowerShell prompt type

- `az login`

The az login command will open a new web browser window and ask your to log into your Azure Subscription account.

Edit: Another option, you could also login in the command line:

```
az login -u <username> -p <password>
```

- Next we need to generate a SAS token.

We can do this by running this command in the Azure CLI window:

`az iot hub generate-sas-token --duration -n`

Now we have our SAS Token, we can start monitoring the hub messages by running the following command:

`az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name`

for more details please read: https://github.com/AzureIoTGBB/How-To-Monitor-Azure-IoT-Hub-with-Azure-CLI-2.0

#### Azure Function

- Create a Function App by clicking the below in the Azure Portal “Create New” blade. This is the “container” which holds your functions.
- Once the Function is created, navigate to the “Create new function from template page”:
  Select IoT Hub (Event Hub) and Javascript or C# as the language
  Conveniently, Azure Functions will create the connection with IoT Hub for you after selecting this template,
- Next you just have to click on the "new" button and select the proper IoT Hub instance:
- Click "Create" and the Function just created will be triggered by the IoT Hub events
- The function is created with boilerplate code     console logging the messages

Comment: I had to add an extension to the Azure CLI in order for the listed commands to work
`az extension add --name azure-cli-iot-ext`

Comment: You can also login in command line: `az login -u <username> -p <password>`

Comment: Please, update your CLI command. The actual version of it is: `az extension add --name azure-iot`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to **just see the latest messages** coming in is maybe using the [cloud shell in the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/features/cloud-shell/).

From the Portal Home page, open it by clicking the "Shell" icon in the upper right corner.

Then do

```
az extension add --name azure-iot
az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name <youriothubname>
```

With this, the incoming events start to appear in the console.

Comment: Requires extra azure storage costs to set up the cloud shell. This shouldn't be difficult to setup yourself locally but currently, not supported for M1 macs I believe.