# In Azure IoT hub - where do i see MQTT messages that has been sent from a device?

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub

im trying to send messages over the MQTT protocol to Azure IOT hub. 
Im using this code in NodeJS:

```
var clientFromConnectionString = require('azure-iot-device- 
mqtt').clientFromConnectionString;
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var connectionString = 'HostName=myhostname.azure- 
devices.net;DeviceId=Arsenal;SharedAccessKey=mysharedaccesskey';

var client = clientFromConnectionString(connectionString);


var connectCallback = function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Could not connect: ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Client connected');
    var message = new Message('some data from my device');
    client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
      console.log("Message sent!");
      if (err) console.log(err.toString());
 });

client.on('message', function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  client.complete(msg, function () {
    console.log('completed');
   });
  });
 }
};

client.open(connectCallback);
```

This prints "Client connected!" and "Message sent!"
Maybe this is a really silly question, but where in IoT Hub can i see the message that has been sent?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381303/how-to-test-messages-arriving-in-azure-iothub) can help?

Comment: You can also use Azure CLI to monitor the events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-iot-ext-az-iot-hub-monitor-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three suggestions:

#### Azure CLI

- At a PowerShell prompt type

  - az login

  The az login command will open a new web browser window and ask your to log into your Azure Subscription account.
- Next we need to generate a SAS token.  We can do this by running this command in the Azure CLI window:

  - az iot hub generate-sas-token --duration  -n
- Now we have our SAS Token, we can start monitoring the hub messages by running the following command:

  - az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name

for more details please read: https://github.com/AzureIoTGBB/How-To-Monitor-Azure-IoT-Hub-with-Azure-CLI-2.0

#### Azure Function

- Create a Function App by clicking the below in the Azure Portal “Create New” blade. This is the “container” which holds your functions.
- Once the Function is created, navigate to the “Create new function from template page”:
  Select IoT Hub (Event Hub) and Javascript or C# as the language
  Conveniently, Azure Functions will create the connection with IoT Hub for you after selecting this template,
- Next you just have to click on the "new" button and select the proper IoT Hub instance:
- Click "Create" and the Function just created will be triggered by the IoT Hub events
- The function is created with boilerplate code     console logging the messages

#### Device Explorer for IoT Hub Devices

On the read me of the [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer) it describes how to download, build and use the Device Explorer tool:

- You can either download a pre-built version of Device Explorer or build it yourself.
- [Configure the IoT Hub Connection](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#configure-an-iot-hub-connection)
- Click on the Management tab

Also there is a another thread that can be useful since it describes how to use it:  [How to test Messages arriving in Azure IoTHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381303/how-to-test-messages-arriving-in-azure-iothub)