# Azure IOT Message Body, ContentEncoding Method not found

Tags: azure, iot

References :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/iot-hub-message-routing-now-with-routing-on-message-body/

[How to send a json object instead of a string with Azure Client SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288169/how-to-send-a-json-object-instead-of-a-string-with-azure-client-sdk)

I can send IOT messages successfully and store these messages in Azure storage.
On reviewing the messages, the body is BASE64 encoded. I want the JSON within the body in the message to be shown as a string so I can process the contents in ADF.

I have added to my message the properties as below, as suggested by the reference posts above:

```
mes.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
mes.ContentType = "application/json";
```

On doing this, I get the message below when I try and send the message. The app compiles ok, it's only when my app sends the message.

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message.set_ContentEncoding(System.String)'.
```

Comment the lines out, and it works fine again.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 private async void SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsyncDcbIot(DcbIotPayload dataPayload)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataPayload.did))
        {
            DpmIotLog.LogToFile("no deviceId in data payload", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.High);
            return;
        }
        
        dataPayload.t = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPayload);
        var messageSize = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(messageString);

        DpmIotLog.LogToFile($"Message Len {messageSize}", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Verbose);
        DpmIotLog.LogToFile($"Message {messageString}", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Verbose);


        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageString);
        using (var mes = new Message(messageBytes))
        {
            // Set message body type and content encoding. 
            mes.ContentEncoding = "utf-8";
            mes.ContentType = "application/json";

            try
            {

                if (messageSize > 7000)
                {
                    var ex = new Exception("PayloadSizeException");
                    DpmIotLog.LogToFile("payload over 7000 bytes", ex, DpmIotLog.LogCondition.High);
                    throw ex;
                }

                DpmIotLog.LogToFile($"Submitting Message to HUB", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Verbose);

                Task t = deviceClient.SendEventAsync(mes);

                if (await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(10000)) == t)
                {
                    MessageSent?.Invoke(true);
                    DpmIotLog.LogToFile($"Message Sent", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Verbose);
                    deviceClient.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageSent?.Invoke(false);
                    DpmIotLog.LogToFile($"Message Fail", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Verbose);
                    deviceClient.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (DeviceNotFoundException)
            {
                DpmIotLog.LogToFile($"invalid or disabled device ID : {dataPayload.did}", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Critical);
            }
            catch (DeviceDisabledException)
            {
                DpmIotLog.LogToFile($"IOT disabled device ID : {dataPayload.did}", DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Critical);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DpmIotLog.LogToFile("task to upload payload to server failure", ex, DpmIotLog.LogCondition.Critical);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an entirely new project and updated all the dependences to the latest versions. This resolved the issue. (I was using a old IOT project as a starting point)